# List View - scroll to bottom, WITHOUT skipping items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that's being populated from a custom CursorAdapter. Every item(-row) has a checkbox.

A couple of important facts before I explain the problem:

**A.** The checked/unchecked data is coming from the DB.

**B**. I save the location of every "checkbox" to a boolean array.

**C.** There is no way to know which checkbox is checked, without re-querying the   until I scroll to it, since it is not loaded yet.

Problem is:

I am trying to create a "Clear All" button. for every "checked" checkbox, I will have to update the column in the DB to "no".

I tried `LV.scrollTo(lastItem)`, and then check if each row is checked or not:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        boolean t = itemChecked.get(i); //check the array to see if this row is checked
        if (t == true) {
        //set to "no" in the DB
        }
```

but it seemed that it "skipped" over the rows between the one that were displayed on the very top and the very bottom.
I figured it's happening because they are not getting rendered, and therefore not saving the "checked" state in the array.

Then I tried this little piece of code that will scroll through every 5 rows or so, but it still didn't work:

```
 int j = 0; 
//loop times is the array.count() over the amount of rows that fit in the screen 
     while(j < loopTimes){ 
 int n = j*fitToScreen;

 Listview.setSelection(n);

   j++ ;
 }
```

It just jumps straight to the bottom, without reading those rows.

My guess is that there's not enough time for the rows to render.

Is there any other way of scrolling down without skipping the rows, or accomplishing what that am trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all values are coming from database...then simply change the value of all the rows in the database and then invalidate your listview.

Comment: I've thought of that, but it will take too long, I will have to requery every row, and then if it is set to "yes", set to "no". see fact#3

Comment: Since you are doing Clear All, you not need to check for "yes" value. I think if you run following sql query on your database and invalidate your listview...your purpose will be solved
   UPDATE table_name SET check_box = 'no'; Does this make sense ??

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I did that, but it took waaaay to long - . I guess I'll have to do it if I don't find a better solution.